# socket.io not transmitting to browser

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I seem to have socket.io setup and trying to emit some tweets, but they're not appearing in the browser. This is what I'm getting in the console:

```
GET / 304 16ms
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized LYlpc7dcpLyHCFcKYUJy
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/LYlpc7dcpLyHCFcKYUJy
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client LYlpc7dcpLyHCFcKYUJy
   debug - client authorized for 
   debug - websocket writing 1::
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"tweets","args":[{"user":"AaronNewport97","text":"You're not your","latitude":51.56764399,"longitude":0.49722754}]}
51.56764399 0.49722754
```

Here's the relevant code from app.js:

```
if(data.geo!=null){
        latitude = data.geo.coordinates[0];
        longitude = data.geo.coordinates[1];

   io.sockets.volatile.emit('tweets', {
        user: data.user.screen_name,
        text: data.text,
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude
    });
}
```

And this is what I've got on the html side:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect();
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var tweetList = $('ul.tweets');
        socket.on('tweet', function (data) {
            tweetList .prepend('<li>' + data.user + ': ' + data.text + '</li>'); 
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

In the broswer console, I've got:

```
Request URL:ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/1/websocket/vBFWuusMIQbO9PeJZv8p
Request Method:GET
Status Code:101 Switching Protocols
```

And it looks like the connection is pending. Why is it doing this?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: The message you send is named `tweets`, but your browser is waiting for a message named `tweet` (without the `-s`).

Comment: Perfect - thanks very much. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message you send is named `tweets`, but your browser is waiting for a message named `tweet` (without the `-s`).

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

`io.sockets.volatile.emit('tweets', {`

for this

`socket.volatile.emit('tweet', {`